# Calculate time difference adding an object to an array list vs linked list

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a Java class project where I created both an array and a linked list from a previous assignment and the second half of the project is this:

> Calculate the time (in milliseconds) it takes to add the 5th object to the middle (index 1 or 2) of the ArrayList (1 point)
>
> Calculate the time (in milliseconds) it takes to add the 5th object to the middle (index 1 or 2) of the LinkedList (1 point)
>
> Print out both of these time calculations on the screen to see which one is faster. (the one with less time is faster).  Then, write a comment in your code to explain in your own words why one insert was faster than the other insert (1 point)

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
package pugs;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DogNode headObj;
    DogNode nodeObj1;
    DogNode nodeObj2;
    DogNode nodeObj3;
    DogNode nodeObj4;
    DogNode currObj;

    Dog dog1 = new Dog("Todd", 2.1, 21);
    Dog dog2 = new Dog("Nice Pete", 2.3, 25);
    Dog dog3 = new Dog("Pat", 2.0, 18);
    Dog dog4 = new Dog("Ray Smuckles", 1.5, 25);
    Dog dog5 = new Dog("Roast Beef", 2.5, 17);

    headObj = new DogNode(dog1);

    nodeObj1 = new DogNode(dog2);
    headObj.insertAfter(nodeObj1);

    nodeObj2 = new DogNode(dog3);
    nodeObj1.insertAfter(nodeObj2);

    nodeObj3 = new DogNode(dog4);
    nodeObj2.insertAfter(nodeObj3);

    nodeObj4 = new DogNode(dog5);
    headObj.insertAfter(nodeObj4);

    currObj = headObj;
    while (currObj != null) {
        currObj.printNodeData();
        currObj = currObj.getNext();
    }

    ArrayList<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();

    list.add(dog1);
    list.add(dog2);
    list.add(dog3);
    list.add(dog4);
    list.add(1,dog5);

    }

}
```

My professor has given this hint:

```
  long startTime= System.nanoTime();
  //code to insert here
  long endTime = System.nanoTime();
  double difference = (endTime - startTime) / 1e6;
  System.out.println("Time to insert: " + difference + " ms\n");
```

How do I use this hint code to calculate the time?

Comment: That's a strange assignment. Does your professor know that this kind of timing will give results that are near to useless? The size of the problem is to small.

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend using a library such as [Dropwizard-metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/) where you can make use of `Timer` to calculate the time and `console reporter` to print the values in the console. You might as well use other reporters to extract the data points and visualize it.

For further reference , [Getting started with dropwizard-metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/)